# Is there a way to pass an array using enviromentObject

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of `MyItem`.

```
var array:[MyItem]
```

I was expecting that to fail, but I have tried to pass `array` using

```
.environmentObject(array)
```

Obviously it failed.

> Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that '[MyItems]' conform to 'ObservableObject'

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the type of `MyItem`? You should probably be using `environment`, not `environmentObject`

Comment: No, there is a whole chain of things that has to connect for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the array inside a class conform ObservableObject, and then you can pass it normally

```swift
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    ....
    //Add @Published to enable binding to any views using this property
    @Published var array: [MyItem] = []
}

@StateObject private var modelData = ModelData()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(modelData)
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent idea! Thanks

Comment: It's no big deal.